# Resubmission after Information update

Tags: action, actions-on-google

In need of a help.

Hi, I need to change information and logo of my Action, live by 2 months.
If I modify information in Directory information, is it necessary to re-submit action ora can I release without review?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-submit for a review.